# Getting from Victoria Falls airport to town

Tags: airport-transfer, zimbabwe, victoria-falls

What are my options for getting from Victoria Falls airport into town? All I have seen so far are taxis and pre-booked accommodation transfers.

Comment: Sometimes you can either ask or watch the local people. I did this in Hanoi, Vietnam four or five years ago. All the foreigners except me took expensive taxis or tourist buses. All the Vietnamese plus me took the local bus for a fraction of a fraction of the price and a much more memorable arrival (-:

Comment: Normally that's the sort of thing id do, but I have a relatively short time in Vic Falls and I want to pack a lot in so planning is going to be crucial.

Comment: I have another trick that worked for me when I tried it in Bangkok: If you can spot an Israeli backpackers in the airport ask them how they got there and how much they paid. Israeli backpackers always have tiny budgets (just got out of the army) and are very good hagglers (-:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a ton of taxis who come in to meet the planes.  Try and buddy up with another tourist if possible and save on cost, and be aware - you're a tourist, taxi drivers will sometimes ask 10x the normal price just to see if you'll take it - do ask a couple of drivers before accepting one.

Acceptable price is US$25, but if you're a good negotiator you can get this down to $20.  It is about 22km out of town.  Price is per taxi, so more people = less money for you ;)

And yes, they want US$, although may take Rand.

There are also airpor transfers, for around US$12 if you just want that, for more details you can email info@victoriafalls-guide.net to book a transfer.  There are several companies, but this address will do the dealing on your behalf, and someone will meet you at the airport.

As a final thought - check with your hotel - they may well offer airport pick-up, either free or as an optional add-on!

Comment: So if you don't book something there is a $30USD per head charge, there is only one taxi company that operates there.

Comment: returning to the airport its $30 a taxi not $30 a head. also a lot of accommodation offers shuttles to the airport but not from. the adventure lodge where I'm staying is charging $13 per head.

Comment: Didn't I say per taxi, not per head?

Comment: Sorry I was commenting on my comment. Last time I was airport to town this time I was the other way round.